# Pass information from referenced class back to calling form

Tags: .net, vb.net, events

We have a Windows Forms application that instantiates a dll, and inside that dll instantiates classes.

**EDIT:**

So the process is like this:

*FORM > alpsClient (DLL) > Class*

I want to update the `backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged` event on the FORM from the Class.

**END EDIT**

In the class objects work is done that can take quite a while.

I'd like to pass back some type of progress back from the class to the calling form.

I guess I need to use events.

But how should I reference the form which kicked off the process in a background worker.

Here is the code that instantiates the dll object:

```
   Private Sub alpsManual_bgw_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles alpsManual_bgw.DoWork
    Try

        Dim arg As String = CStr(e.Argument)
        objDoc = New alpsClient

        '* Set variables and start
        ' CUT ...

        If fromArchive Then
            '********************************************
            '* Manual Settings                          *
            '********************************************
             ' SET PROPERTIES
             ... CUT for brevity
            '********************************************
        End If

        objDoc.docMap()
        '* Wait until isComplete before starting next
        Do
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Loop Until objDoc.isComplete

    Catch ex As Exception
```

and here is the code that will instantiate the class inside `alpsClient.docMap`:

```
Dim objControl As Object = Nothing

Select Case docRef
    Case "YL0PF"                    'Arrears Advice
        objControl = New YL0PF
    Case "YL2PF"                    'Arrears with Additional Interest
        objControl = New YL2PF

... etc
```

then:

```
objControl.dbConn = masterDB
objControl.docRef = docRef
objControl.table2Format = table2Format
objControl.newAddressFormat = newAddressFormat
objControl.dteinp = runDate
' Start
docMap = ""
If Not objControl.Controller() Then docMap = "Errors"
```

and it is inside the class referenced by `objControl` that I would like to send a progress message back to the calling form ... probably using an event.

Or is this a very bad idea?

Comment: Why is this tagged C#?

Comment: Sounds reasonable enough. The only think to take care of is that if the event is raised by code running on the background thread, the code that processes the event will also be on the background thread. If this tries to update the GUI is will crash: the GUI must only be updated on the GUI thread. This is relatively easy to do by using either .Invoke methods on GUI objects from the background thread, or using the SynchronizationContext object.

Comment: so I need to register an event, then raise the event or call the backgroundworker 'ProgressChanged' event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make sure all your control classes inherit from a common base class, something like:

```
Public MustInherit Class ControlBase
   Protected Sub New()
   End Sub

   Public Event ProgressEvent As EventHandler<Of ProgressEventArgs>

   Protected Sub RaiseProgressEvent(current As Integer, maximum as Integer)
       RaiseEvent ProgressEvent(Me, New ProgressEventArgs(current, maximum)
   End Sub

End Class

Public Class ProgressEventArgs : Inherits EventArgs
   Private _current as Integer
   Private _maximum as Integer

   Public Sub New(current As Integer, maximum as Integer)
      _current = current
      _maximum = maximum
   End Sub

   Public ReadOnly Property Current() As Integer
      Get
         Return _current
      End Get
   End Property

   Public ReadOnly Property Maximum() As Integer
      Get
         Return _maximum
      End Get
   End Property
End Class
```

Then each of your YL0PF, YL2PF, etc classed inherit from this class and call RaiseProgressEvent.

When you instiante the classes, do something like this...

```
Dim objControl As ControlBase = Nothing

Select Case docRef
    Case "YL0PF"                    'Arrears Advice
        objControl = New YL0PF
    Case "YL2PF"                    'Arrears with Additional Interest
        objControl = New YL2PF

... etc
End Select

AddHandler objControl.ProgressEvent, AddressOf OnProgressEvent
objControl.DoSomething()  ' <- lengthy process will raise ProgressEvent
....

Sub OnProgressEvent(sender as Object, e As ProgressEventArgs)
  ' Update your progress control - pay attention to "simon at rcl"'s comment above
  ' about making sure this is done on the GUI thread.  You will have to use Invoke 
  ' if the event will be fired from another thread.

  ' OP mentioned in a comment that they are using a BackgroundWorker so the
  ' ProgressEvent will be called in a background thread which can't change the
  ' UI.  So you would call its ReportProgress which will in turn raise its own
  ' ProgressChanged event but on the UI thread.
  backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt(e.Current / e.Maximum * 100))
End Sub 

Private Sub backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged( _
            sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) _
            Handles backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
      ' This will be called on the UI thread, so we can update the ProgressBar
      Me.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 thanks for your answer, I have edited my question to make it clearer and give more specifics.

Comment: please see the edit to my question - I really need to update the form using the `backgroundworker_OnProgressChanged` event - so I need to be able to bind to an event on the `alpsClient` dll that is raised by the class?

Comment: That is correct, I have modified the example to show using the backgroundWorker.ReportProgress method.